# TMultiView on Frame causes AV

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

When placing a TMultiview control on a frame and trying to re-open that frame in the IDE causes an AV and unable to view it.

It is a known issue and reported to EMB. The issue has been reported to the new Quality Portal here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9621. Note that you need to be logged on to view this report. For those that don't have an account, here is what the report looks like as of the time of writing:

[image]

Does anyone know of a workaround, or can come up with a workaround?

Comment: I followed your link and it revealed nothing. Please include details here.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps i cannot link directly do it.

I have supplied a different link

Comment: I see no evidence that this has been reported either to QC or to their new system (https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) Do you have an issue number?

Comment: The reference number seems to be RSP-9621

If you search for TMultiview it appears there

Comment: Thanks. I can see it now. Their stupid system won't let you view items unless you are logged on. Which is lame.

Answer (score 3):

There is workaround that will enable you to view and edit that frame, but it involves some manual handling of both .pas and .fmx files

Let's say you have created frame with TMultiView component on it.

Your .pas file looks like:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, 
  FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.MultiView;

type
  TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
    MultiView1: TMultiView;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

and your .fmx file looks like:

```
object Frame3: TFrame3
  Size.Width = 561.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 408.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 0
  object MultiView1: TMultiView
    Size.Width = 250.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 408.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end
```

In order to successfully open your frame you have to open both files in some editor like Notepad.
Replace TFrame with TForm in your .pas file class declaration,

```
  TFrame3 = class(TForm)
```

then cut out TFrame specific properties from .fmx file (and store it somewhere because you will need to copy them back after you completed the editing)

```
  Size.Width = 561.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 408.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 0
```

Now you can freely open your Frame (Form) in IDE, and do whatever you need with it. After you are done, save the files, close them in IDE and again edit .pas and .fmx files in Notepad.

```
  TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
```

and replace TForm specific properties that IDE inserted with your original TFrame ones

```
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop, iPhone, iPad]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this issue for about a week now, and till today was under the impression that my XE7 installation might be corrupt. In the mean time, what I did to work around this issue has been to  *cut* the `TMultiView` with all its children from the `.FMX` file, open the frame in IDE, and *paste*. The only drawback is you have to link events again.